# What is the root user password for freshly installed MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance of AWS and I have installed MySQL through the following command:

```
sudo dnf install mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch.rpm -y
sudo dnf install mysql-community-server -y
```

Now MySQL is installed successfully and but it didn't gave me chance to add password. Now how can I login into MySQL without a password?

I try to login by adding:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

in

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

It's working fine but when I remove

```
skip-grant-tables
```

from config file and try to login using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it asks for password and I don't know that as I didn't setup the password while installing MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need follow these steps:

1. Stop mysql:

   `sudo systemctl stop mysqld`
2. Start mysql in safe mode

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
3. Connect to mysql again

   `mysql -u root`
4. Reset the root password

   `USE mysql; UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('your_new_password') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. Exit to mysql and restart it

   `exit;`

   `sudo pkill mysqld`
6. Start mysql again and use the new password

   `sudo systemctl start mysqld`

Comment: sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
sudo: mysqld_safe: command not found

Comment: @Ritesh maybe here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html can help you too.